What all are the elements in an Autosar DEXT ARXML file and the "check rules" after creating a DEXT?
I am trying to contribute to an open-source python code in git which creates a DEXT ARXML file from a set of inputs (doc, xls). I want to know/ get a list of elements that SHOULD be in it and all a similar list of all the "checking rules". I would like to build a checker module also.
I've started reading the R23-11 version of the following documents:

Autosar TPS DEXT document but it is 700 odd pages and is taking more time than I can manage.
XML schema production rules. Got the XSD for a generic ARXML from autosar website. I can use this to create the structure for the DEXT's ARXML.
XML serialization rules.


AUTOSAR Metamodel (where it is specified about the elements, type, order, multiplicity etc.,) against the generated DEXT to validate it.
e.g., Metamodel xsd - AUTOSAR_FO_MMOD_XMLSchema.zip\AUTOSAR_00052.xsd.
There are multiple possible checkers or tools which could be used, such as Notepad++ or ARTOP.
